# ¿Como escuchar evento de boton y ejecutar un metodo en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Quiero hacer una especie de tienda online ficticia y necesito hacer que cuando toca el usuario un botón con un producto y luego con otro producto, el precio de ambos se sume y que salga una alert mostrando la suma.

```
const costoproducto1 = 2400
const costoproducto2 = 4000
const costoproducto3 = 2400
const costoproducto4 = 2800
const costoproducto5 = 3100
const costoproducto6 = 4000


 
function sumar(prod1,prod2,prod3,prod4,prod5,prod6) {
return prod1 + prod2 + prod3 + prod4 + prod5 + prod6
}

let primerprod = Number(costoproducto1)
let segundoprod = Number(costoproducto2)
let tercerprod = Number(costoproducto3)
let cuartoprod = Number(costoproducto4)
let quintoprod = Number(costoproducto5)
let sexxtoprod = Number(costoproducto6)

let preciofinal =sumar(primerprod, segundoprod)
```

[image: Esta seria la imagen. Quiero que cuando el usuario toque el agregar al carrito de dos productos se sume y aparezca una alert indicando el precio final]

Comment: ENtonces, implementa el método sumar que reciba sólo dos parámetros (los dos productos? los dos valores? tu decisión) y genere el alert que buscas. Ya tienes un método que hace una suma, haz otro que sume los dos valores que necesitas. Tampoco tenemos idea de qué botones hablas ni del evento asociado, porque nada de ese código está aquí. Si quieres ayuda más específica, podrías ir a [edit] y ampliar tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar eventos en tus botones para que hagan ciertas instrucciones cuando interactuemos con ellas, es decir, al usar el método [**`addEventListener()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) le decimos que cuando ocurra cierto evento (en este caso, al hacer "click"), se ejecute cierta instrucción:

```
botonProducto1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  total += costoproducto1;
  totales.innerHTML = total;
});
```

Te doy un ejemplo básico en donde te explico línea por línea:

```js
const costoproducto1 = 2400; // defino el precio del primer producto.
const costoproducto2 = 4000; // defino el precio del segundo producto.

const botonProducto1 = document.getElementById('producto1'); // obtengo al botón del producto 1.
const botonProducto2 = document.getElementById('producto2'); // obtengo al botón del producto 2.

let totales = document.getElementById("totales"); // obtengo al span del precio total.
const mostrarTotal = document.getElementById('mostrarTotal'); // obtengo al botón del alert.

let total = 0; // inicializo a total, donde se acumularán los totales.

// a los 3 botones, le agrego un evento que al hacer "click" ocurra ciertas instrucciones.
botonProducto1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  total += costoproducto1; // sumo el precio del producto 1 cada vez que le haga clic al botón del producto 1.
  totales.innerHTML = total; // y muestro el resultado de la suma en el span "totales".
});

botonProducto2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  total += costoproducto2; // sumo el precio del producto 2 cada vez que le haga clic al botón del producto 2.
  totales.innerHTML = total; // y muestro el resultado de la suma en el span "totales".
});

mostrarTotal.addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert(`El precio total es: ${total}`); // aquí muestro un alert del total final al hacer clic en el botón "mostrarTotal".
});
```

```html
<button id="producto1">Producto 1</button>
<button id="producto2">Producto 2</button>
<button id="mostrarTotal">Mostrar total</button>
<br><br>
<span>El precio total es: <span id="totales"></span></span>
```